# Heroku Shield: no ps:exec?

Tags: php, heroku, chroot, fpm, nextcloud

I have installed nextcloud successfully on heroku, and then to heroku shield.

I'm having some issues trying to diagnos my app errors?! Mostly becuase I do not have

`heroku ps:exec`

instead I only have: `heroku run bash`

I can see they are **NOT** the same live environement. Everytime I try to execute an `occ` command I get:

`The current PHP memory limit is below the recommended value of 512MB.`

I know this is not true because when I spin up the drive I receive:

```
2019-04-17T21:59:11.405086+00:00 app[web.2]: DOCUMENT_ROOT changed to 'server/'
2019-04-17T21:59:11.405100+00:00 app[web.2]: Using PHP-FPM configuration include 'fpm_custom.conf'
2019-04-17T21:59:11.431612+00:00 app[web.2]: Optimizing defaults for IX dyno....
2019-04-17T21:59:11.446380+00:00 app[web.2]: 1 processes at 2GB memory limit.
2019-04-17T21:59:11.449664+00:00 app[web.2]: Starting php-fpm...
2019-04-17T21:59:13.458996+00:00 app[web.2]: Starting httpd...
2019-04-17T21:59:14.408040+00:00 heroku[web.2]: State changed from starting to up
```

Also, during the install I tried to monitor files, such as `config.php`. I knew they were getting changed, yet a `cat server/config/config.php` showed me nothing was changing.

So, I know this is some different chroot environment.

How can I actually see my live files?

Thanks for the help.

Below is a list of config snippets:
* adding to `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
  php_value upload_max_filesize 768M
  php_value post_max_size 768M
  php_value memory_limit 1024M
  php_value mbstring.func_overload 0
  php_value default_charset 'UTF-8'
  php_value output_buffering 0
  <IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv htaccessWorking true
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

- adding to `.user.ini`:

```
upload_max_filesize=2G
post_max_size=2G
memory_limit=2G
mbstring.func_overload=0
always_populate_raw_post_data=-1
default_charset='UTF-8'
output_buffering=0
```

- adding to `fpm_custom.conf`:

```
php_value[upload_max_filesize] = 2G
php_value[post_max_size] = 2G
php_value[memory_limit] = 2G
php_value[mbstring.func_overload] = 0
php_value[default_charset] = 'UTF-8'
php_value[output_buffering] = 0

php_value[apc.enable_cli] = 1
```

- and of course the `Procfile` reads

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -F fpm_custom.conf server/
```

Thanks for any help!

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not intentionally trying to answer my own question here, but I received a response to my heroku ticket: https://help.heroku.com/706339. Here is heroku's reply:

> You're correct that Shield Spaces do not support `ps:exec` due to compliance requirements. That means there's no way to traverse a running dyno to see file changes in a Shield Space without manually logging the details to your application logs.
>
> When you spin up a new dyno with the `heroku run bash` command it does not start Apache, so the changes in `fpm_custom.conf` are not going to be initialized. You might try manually running the `vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -F fpm_custom.conf server/` from inside that dyno to better understand how those configurations work together.